# ng-switch is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-switch

Maybe the use of the 2-ways binding and `$watch` is still not very clear to me.. but I was expecting that this piece of code should work!

I have a *topNavbar* directive in my *index.html* page. The *topNavbar* should show the *loginButton* if the user is not logged, otherwise a *loggedinButton* if he is already logged.

So I have a `ng-switch` in the *topNavbar*, looking at the *isLogged* attribute of the *CurrentUserService*. I guess this is something like `$watch(CurrentUserService.isLogged)`.

However, when I change `CurrentUserService.isLogged` to `true`, the `ng-switch` is not immediately updated. It gets updated after any my action, like clicking on a button o changing the view.
Why it's not working as I expect?

This is my code:

**index.html**

```
<html lang="it" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="epoiApp">
  ...
  <body style="overflow-y: auto;">
    ...
    <top-navbar></top-navbar>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**directive template topNavbar**

```
<div ng-switch on="navbarCtrl.isLogged()">
  <div ng-switch-when="false">
    <login-button></login-button>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="true">
    <loggedin-button></loggedin-button>
  </div>                                            
</div>
```

---

**controller navbarCtrl**

```
controller:function(CurrentUserService)
            {
             this.isLogged = function()
                            {return CurrentUserService.isLogged();} 
            }
```

---

**CurrentUserService**

```
.service('CurrentUserService', function () 
  {   
   // initialization
   _islogged = false;

   this.isLogged = function() 
        { return _islogged; };

  }
```

---

thank you

Comment: Just a wild guess here: Did you forget a $scope.apply() in your directive by any chance?

Comment: I don't use  $scope.$apply()...  I thought it was automatic. Why should I manually use  $scope.$apply()  here, while anywhere else is not needed? (I mean, in all the other ng-repeat, ng-model, {{ctrl.value}}, etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tfCrzcVUJXKzb83ozlGm?p=preview).

Angular kicks off a digest cycle when there is a change to the model (which is why after you interacted with the UI in some way you noticed it update).

A change in a closure variable inside a service is not part of the model, so you need to manually `$scope.$apply()` to start a digest cycle when you know this variable has been updated.